# How to create Azure My SQL DB by using ARM template

Tags: mysql, azure

I have to create one Azure My SQL DB by automation not manually? Can anyone help me to create it through ARM template.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an ARM Template to Create Azure MySQL over Linux VM. You can customize it as per your needs.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "mysqlPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Root password password for the MySQL database."
      }
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Username for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Password for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Free",
        "Shared",
        "Basic",
        "Standard",
        "Premium"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Free",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The pricing tier for the App Service plan."
      }
    },
    "svcPlanSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "F1",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The instance size of the app."
      }
    },
    "prefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Prefix for all the resources."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "imagePublisher": "Canonical",
    "imageOffer": "UbuntuServer",
    "ubuntuOSVersion": "15.10",
    "OSDiskName": "osdiskfordockersimple",
    "nsgName": "[concat(parameters('prefix'),'NSG')]",
    "nicName": "[concat(parameters('prefix'),'VMNic')]",
    "dnsNameForPublicIP": "[parameters('prefix')]",
    "extensionName": "DockerExtension",
    "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16",
    "subnetName": "Subnet",
    "subnetPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
    "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS",
    "storageName": "wpac",
    "publicIPAddressName": "[concat(parameters('prefix'),'PublicIP')]",
    "publicIPAddressType": "Dynamic",
    "serverFarmName": "[concat(parameters('prefix'),'SrvFrm')]",
    "vmStorageAccountContainerName": "vhds",
    "vmName": "[concat(parameters('prefix'),'DockerVM')]",
    "vmSize": "Basic_A1",
    "virtualNetworkName": "[concat(parameters('prefix'),'VNET')]",
    "vnetID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "nsgID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups',variables('nsgName'))]",
    "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetID'),'/subnets/',variables('subnetName'))]",
    "webAppName": "[concat(parameters('prefix'),'WebApp')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[variables('storageName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "accountType": "[variables('storageAccountType')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "[variables('publicIPAddressType')]",
        "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "[variables('dnsNameForPublicIP')]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('nsgID')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]",
              "networkSecurityGroup": {
                "id": "[variables('nsgID')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
              },
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "name": "[variables('nsgName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "securityRules": [
          {
            "name": "mysql",
            "properties": {
              "description": "Allow MySQL",
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationPortRange": "3306",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "Internet",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
              "access": "Allow",
              "priority": 100,
              "direction": "Inbound"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "ssh",
            "properties": {
              "description": "Allow SSH",
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationPortRange": "22",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "Internet",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
              "access": "Allow",
              "priority": 110,
              "direction": "Inbound"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "name": "[variables('vmName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[variables('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computername": "[variables('vmName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "[variables('imagePublisher')]",
            "offer": "[variables('imageOffer')]",
            "sku": "[variables('ubuntuOSVersion')]",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "name": "osdisk1",
            "vhd": {
              "uri": "[concat('http://',variables('storageName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/',variables('vmStorageAccountContainerName'),'/',variables('OSDiskName'),'.vhd')]"
            },
            "caching": "ReadWrite",
            "createOption": "FromImage"
          }
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',variables('nicName'))]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'/', variables('extensionName'))]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "DockerExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.1",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "compose": {
            "db": {
              "image": "mysql",
              "ports": [
                "3306:3306"
              ],
              "volumes": [
                "/var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
              ],
              "environment": [
                "[concat('MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=', parameters('mysqlPassword'))]",
                "MYSQL_DATABASE=wpacMySQL",
                "[concat('MYSQL_USER=', parameters('adminUsername'))]",
                "[concat('MYSQL_PASSWORD=', parameters('mysqlPassword'))]"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('serverFarmName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "sku": {
          "name": "[parameters('svcPlanSize')]",
          "tier": "[parameters('sku')]",
          "capacity": 1
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I need a separate Azure my SQL db not in VM. Please give me some idea.